# Jetty 9.4.9 ignoring jetty-logging.properties

Tags: logging, jetty

I have a java webapp deployed on CentOS with jetty 9.4.9. It's all working except that i can't get logging to work right. I want the StdErrLog to capture all my logging as described in https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/default-logging-with-stderrlog.html, but with some tweaks like filtering by loglevel.

I have added console-capture and jetty logging via:

java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --add-to-start=console-capture

java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --add-to-start=logging-jetty

I do see a log file in logs/2018_12_20.jetty.log but resources/jetty-logging.properties does not seem to get included. At least i think it doesn't because it is not filtering the logrecords as requested. Also jetty does not output any error when i add a gibberish line.

Content jetty-logging.properties:

org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog

org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO

ca.uhn.fhir.LEVEL=INFO

I still see in the logs:

```
13:45:34.190 [qtp2051450519-10] DEBUG ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner - Scanning resource class: org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Bundle
```

ca.uhn.fhir.LEVEL=INFO seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The class `ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner` would never be processed through the Jetty logging framework.

The logging output you are seeing is from some other logging library that is producing logging events to STDERR and/or STDOUT.

The format of the output is also a tell-tale sign that this is another (non-Jetty) logging framework you are dealing with.

The use of `console-capture` module is simply capturing anything that goes to STDERR/STDOUT and writing to a file.